# A characterization of the integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration, smoothness, derivations

Let $I(f)$ be an endomorphism of the smooth functions with zero value in zero such that:
$$\ln[1+I(f)]=I\left(\frac{f}{1+I(f)}\right).
$$
Then, does it exist $g$ smooth such that:
$$I(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(t)g(t)dt\;?$$

Comment: So $I$ is a linear map $I: C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$? (Just to make sure)

Comment: I'm not sure how to make sense of $\ln[1 + I(f)]$ without some sort of positivity assumption; but doesn't $I(f) = \int_{-1}^x f(t)\mathrm dt$ satisfy your conditions but not your conclusion?

Comment: @LSpice: As an endomorphism $I$ has to satisfy $I(f)(0)=0$. So your $I$ doesn't work.

Comment: @tj_, [ah](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395812/a-characterization-of-the-integral#comment1058729_395812), I see.  I thought "zero value in zero" meant that $I(0) \equiv 0$ (which indeed seemed confusingly redundant), not $I(f)(0) = 0$.  Thanks!

Comment: I suppose that the equation is true for a neighborhood of zero so that there is no problem to define the log.

Comment: We have also to discuss if we have to take $I$ continuous or not in the hypothesis.